# How to manage my application in a container and deploy with no downtime on gcloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment

I have a monolithic application that I am hosting on google cloud.

I am using cloud build that builds my docker image when I push to my repository.

Other than using Kubernetes, what other options do I have to push my latest docker image to my web instances in a rolling update to not bring my website down?

I cant' seem to find any documentation other than Kubernetes related.

I believe I should be building a instance template that has my latest docker image.  Not sure how to make this happen in an automated fashion.

Comment: Look at Google Cloud Run https://cloud.google.com/run

Comment: Sounds like you are running docker on instance without any orchestration, in that case I am afraid its hard to do. What I will suggest is try to run your application on google-managed https://cloud.google.com/run or introduce docker-swarm if you are willing to manage it by yourself https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/